# How to pass values to different views at same time in laravel?

Tags: laravel

**My website has a homepage and admin area.** One section of my homepage has a slider whose image can be manage with admin panel i.e I have created a CRUD specifically for slider.

But the problem is that admin panel has his own view where he can see all images stored in a tabular manner.

**I want to pass values to my homepage also so that images on slider also changes but I am not able to pass values to 2 views.**

SliderController has a function called Index

```
public function index()
    {
        $slider = Slider::all();
        return view('slider.index')->withSlider($slider);
    }
```

slider.index

```
@extends('main')

@section('title','OnlineKart | Slider')

@section('content')

    <div class="container container-margin">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h2>Slider Image Details</h2>

                        <a class="btn btn-warning " href="{{route('slider.create')}}">  Create New</a>

                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                  <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Body</th>
                            <th>Image</th>
                            <th>Created At</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach ($slider as $sliders)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $sliders->name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $sliders->description }}</td>
                                    <td><img src="{{asset("images/$sliders->image")}}"  class="img-responsive"></td>
                                    <td>{{ $sliders->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</td>
                                    <td><a href="{{route('slider.edit',$sliders->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></td>
                                    <td>{{  Form::open(['route'=>['slider.destroy',$sliders->id], 'method' => 'DELETE']) }}
                                        {{Form::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', array('type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm'))}}
                                        {{ Form::close() }}</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

homepage

```
<!--Slideshow-->
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="{{'images/thumbcrousel.jpg'}}" alt="img1">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Title Here 1</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam, ex.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="{{'images/thumbcrousel.jpg'}}" alt="img2">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Title Here 2</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam, ex.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="{{'images/thumbcrousel.jpg'}}" alt="img3">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Title Here 3</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam, ex.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="{{'images/thumbcrousel.jpg'}}" alt="img3">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Title Here 4</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam, ex.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**I want to pass value to this homepage also so i can make it dynamic**

I can view all my data in this admin section i.e in slider.index.

**Is there any way to pass value to homepage also so that i can view my image in both the pages simultaneously.**

**both localhost:8000 and localhost:8000/slider/index should show images. One page is for public and one is for admin only.**

Sorry For long Post. Please let me know if its hard to understand I will try to clear. Thanks!

Comment: You would need to pass `Slider::all()` to your 'public' index. Then within your index you would loop through them like you have on your admin page, but rather creating HTML carousel elements

Comment: You want to show changes on `admin` page live on `home`? If yes, you really need to understand the Life Cicle of a HTTP Request and of the Laravel Framework.

Since your homepage is already loaded, you must have some external thing that tells to your page: HEY, YOU NEED TO RELOAD THIS IMAGES.

Comment: read about laravel view composers

Answer (score -1):

I’m not sure what the difficulty is? You have two views, with presumably two controllers. So just pass the data to the view in both scenarios:

```php
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $slider = Slider::all();

        return view('slider.index', compact('slider');
    }
}
```

And…

```php
class SliderController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $slider = Slider::all();

        return view('admin.slider.index', compact('slider');
    }
}
```